# Google Script: Exception: Invalid argument: url (line 63, file "Code") AND Google User Access rejected

Tags: google-apps-script, arguments, google-sheets-api, invalid-argument

1. Google Sheet & WebApp  with Edit Access link "[EXER1010 DDDL Create Dependent Drop Down WebApp](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x_pXE64vO0jbVyR6AiuReE2RiAWWhkTPsbRhR77u6R0/edit#gid=0)") when executed and form submission is OK at developer side, and the records are added successfully in Sheet!Sheet.
2. But on google signed user (editor) in other browser without link, although the form on submit but returns error >'**Exception: Invalid argument: url (line 63, file "Code")**' and no records is added to Sheet!DATA
3. But on google unsigned user (public view) in other browser executed as "user accessing the webapp", (signed in and authorization permitted)  but returns error >'**Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document. (line 34, file "Code")**' and fails to load the form
   no records is added to Sheet!DATA
4. Deployment for 2 works with Shared access (Editor), and the records are added in sheet added records (Pls check Sheet!DATA having all entries TimeStamp on 25-07-2023)
5. Deployment for 3 works when Shared access, and the records are added in sheet (Pls check Sheet!DATA having all entries TimeStamp on 25-07-2023)

**OBSERVED FOR ANYONE WITH GOOGLE ACCOUNT**
6. The webapp execute as "user accessing the webapp" unless shared with  Editor access. Thus when not shared with user, it error for '2' above
7. It evenly fails to execute the link when "user accessing the webapp" permitted as viewer or commentor, on submit it error for '3' above
8. The 'Point 7' thus refers the form submission cannot be done for signed user the Sheet is shared.
9. This creates havoc for granting access to user having webapp link, but tidy process for rejecting link unless editor access is shared

As failed submission at user end, need to deploy and execute as admin and form submission thru link to access by google account user (not for non google account) to add records in the sheet.